# Allow fingerprint login instead of PIN via Azure AD/Endpoint Manager

Tags: windows, azure, entra-id

I'm trying to allow users to log into Windows 10 Enterprise using their laptop fingerprint readers.  On the devices the fingerprint has been set up.  On the login screen, Windows is still demanding the PIN be entered *after* the fingerprint reading has been successfully recognised.

Within MS Endpoint Manager -> Windows Hello for Business I followed the instructions to "Allow biometric authentication", but the PIN prompt still remains.  Can anyone please advise how we allow fingerprint authentication **instead of** the Hello PIN?  I fully appreciate that the PIN must still be configured in case fingerprint readings fail.

We don't have Azure AD Premium if that contributes to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Hello is service that is in charge for unlocking/login to particular one device and can be used only on this device (so no passwords), but still PIN, Smart Card, Camera, Biometrics/fingerprint etc are used..

Since the device will have to have Windows Hello enabled, and fingerprint can fail (broken hand, invalid drivers etc.) PIN is used as fallback method. So, users will have to set PIN also, but later, they can use only fingerprint. Default behavior is to use last login method on Windows lock screen.